# flutter - need to extends State and FormField

Tags: flutter

I neet to create a **statefull** class which create **formFiled**. for this I need to do something like this:

```
class SelectCategories  extends StatefulWidget{
  SelectCategories();

  @override
  _SelectCategoriesState createState() => new _SelectCategoriesState();

}

class _SelectCategoriesState extends State<SelectCategories> extends FormField<List<number>>{

}
```

So I need to extends 2 classed. What is the right way to do this?
I want create a list of categories and allow user to choose from. it should be part of a form. When user click on category, I need to change the state to indicate it

Comment: no, you have to extend `StatefulWidget` only and override `Stayte#build` method

Comment: and where and how to extend FormField?

Comment: what do you need to extend `FormField` for?

Comment: I have a form that one of its field is a list of categories that the user need to choose from. So, I need to wrap it in formField so i can validate it and take the value

Answer (score 1):

you can reference this package 's souce code 
 https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_form_builder

dropdown look like what your need 
https://github.com/danvick/flutter_form_builder/blob/master/lib/src/fields/form_builder_dropdown.dart

and also validator you can reference, this package provide more than 10 builin validator https://github.com/danvick/flutter_form_builder/blob/master/lib/src/form_builder_validators.dart

code snippet of form_builder_dropdown.dart 
it return a FormField and in builder return DropdownButton

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FormField(
      key: _fieldKey,
      enabled: !_readonly,
      initialValue: widget.initialValue,
      validator: (val) {
        for (int i = 0; i < widget.validators.length; i++) {
          if (widget.validators[i](val) != null)
            return widget.validators[i](val);
        }
      },
      onSaved: (val) {
        if (widget.valueTransformer != null) {
          var transformed = widget.valueTransformer(val);
          FormBuilder.of(context)
              ?.setAttributeValue(widget.attribute, transformed);
        } else
          _formState?.setAttributeValue(widget.attribute, val);
      },
      builder: (FormFieldState<dynamic> field) {
        return InputDecorator(
          decoration: widget.decoration.copyWith(
            errorText: field.errorText,
            border: InputBorder.none,
          ),
          child: DropdownButton(
            isExpanded: widget.isExpanded,
            hint: widget.hint,
            items: widget.items,
            value: field.value,
            style: widget.style,
            isDense: widget.isDense,
            disabledHint: widget.disabledHint,
            elevation: widget.elevation,
            iconSize: widget.iconSize,
            onChanged: _readonly
                ? null
```

[image]